# Tree Structure With Just Backbone.js And Js.Tree

Tags: backbone.js, jstree

> I am a newbie to backbone, I am asked to build a tree structure in my application, the tree actually is recursive i.e clicking on a node would render some more child nodes calling a rest api. How do i go about this?
>
> The template goes like this

```
<script id="listtemplate" type="text/template">
 <span></span>
</script>
```

> The model is defined like this

```
Model = function(){
    var sportModel;
    sportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    return{
        newInstance : function(){return sportModel;}}})();
```

> The Collection is defined like this

```
Collection = (function(){

var Model = Model.newInstance();

var Hierarchy = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: sportModel,

    url: function () {
        return this.urlParam;
    },

    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.urlParam = options.urlParam || "";
    },

    sync: mySync,

    parse: function (response) {
        return $.map(response.getElementsByTagName('Child'), function (Xml) {
            return $.xml2json(Xml);
        });
    }
});

return{
    newInstance : function(models,options) { return new Hierarchy(models,options); }
};
```

})();

> I have two views master and children views

```
MasterView = (function() {
'use strict';

var masterView;

masterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
      },

    render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    return this;
},

addOne: function(Model){
    //creating a new child view
   // console.log(Model.toJSON().title);
    var taskView = new ChildView.newInstance({model: Model});
    //appending to the root element
    this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
}

});

return {
    newInstance : function(options) { return new masterView(options); }};})();



    ChildView= (function() {
  'use strict';

  var
    htmlTemplate = _.template( $('#eventAccordionTemplate').html() ), // See templatesSearch.jsp
    expanded = true, // By default the Events Accordion extends to the bottom of the browser window.
    BackboneView, applyStyles;

  /**
   * Apply CSS specific to this view
   * Unfortunately, this View needs to modify its parent wrapper element.
   * Otherwise the layout will break when it's resized.  See templatesSearch.jsp.
   * @param {Object} $elmt
   * @param {Boolean} expand
   */
  applyStyles = function( $elmt, expand ) {

    var
      top   = '2px',
      left  = '2px',
      pos   = 'absolute',
      right = '2px';

    if ( expand ) {

      $elmt.css({
        "position" : pos,
        "top"      : top,
        "left"     : left,
        "right"    : right,
        "bottom"   : "2px"
      });

      $elmt.parent().css( 'bottom', '2px' );

    } else {

      $elmt.css({
        "position" : pos,
        "top"      : top,
        "left"     : left,
        "right"    : right,
        "bottom"   : "50%"
      });

      $elmt.parent().css( 'bottom', '50%' );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If often have to implement trees in Backbones (hierarchies of whatever) and I usually end up just using a single Backbone.Collection (Tree) and a single Backbone.Model (Node).

The nodes have, in addition to their content, something like a parent_id property and an array of children_ids. They also have many methods such as isRoot() (parent_id is null), isLeaf (children_ids is empty), children() method (collection.filter -> node.id in children_ids), parent() method (collection.get parent_id), etc.

The Tree has few method, mostly helpers such as rootNodes() (filter on collection where node.isRoot()).

You don't actually need the children_ids array but it does make things a lot easier. If your backend is, for exemple, a Rails backend with something like act_as_tree gem, then it will be very easy to server this kind of Node model.

Depending on your tree size, you can even consider use promises for children() so that it fetches the missing ids if they haven't been loaded yet in a way that would be less annoying for the view. But in my opinion, that's a bit of an overkill. When clicking on 'expand node' (or whatever you call it), you can always just do a currentModel.fetch(). Then, in your /node/:id route on the server side, you can serve the model for all the direct children and the Node model (client side), you can use the parse function to side-load the children when the server send its reply.

There are millions of way to handle this, and it mostly depend on your tree size/complexity/size of a single Node. If you have just a few dozen nodes with just a few data, you are better off just loading the whole hierarchy at once.  Also keep in mind that you can have one Tree/Node structure for handling the hierarchy between Nodes... and then another collection that is just a normal collection (an 'array') of NodeContent nodes that could be heavier and have more logic centered on displaying/editing a single node. With a backreference to a Node if it needs to know its position in the tree.

It's a very broad question, so I hope this helps, if you have a working base of a code maybe someone can help refine it.

Comment: The whole hierarchy is around 10,000 records, clicking on every node would render child nodes, how do i go about this can you just show me an example.

Comment: Remember that you don't have to stick to conventional backbone constructs to achieve this. See my example above.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will give you some ideas/insight as it's not a complete solution.

When we talk about tree hierarchies we're talking about a composite pattern. To quote wikipedia:

"When dealing with Tree-structured data, programmers often have to discriminate between a Item-node and a branch.This makes code more complex, and therefore, error prone. The solution is an interface that allows treating complex and primitive objects uniformly."

With that in mind here's a basic outline of how I would go about it:

```
/**
 * Item type primitive.
 * A branch or Item can be an item in the tree.
 */
var Item = function (obj) {
  this.children = [];
  _.extend(this, obj); // Bit of a hack to do this blindly.
};

var p = Item.prototype;

/**
 * Nest items within an item.
 * Takes in an array of items and an iterator function for parsing them.
 */
p.add = function (items, func) {
  _.each(items, function (item) {
    var inner = (_.isFunction(func)) ? func(item) : item;
    this.children.push(new Item(inner));
  }, this);
};

/**
 * Patch _.each into prototype as a useful shortcut.
 */
p.each = function () {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(this.children);

  return _.each.apply(_, args);
};

/**
 * Pick a single child by criteria.
 */
p.find = function () {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(this.children);

  return _.where.apply(_, args).shift();
};
```

});

General usage:

```
// Build the tree, starting from the root.
var root = new Item(),
    types = _.uniq(_.pluck(collection, 'name'));

// Build a basic root from collection.
root.add(types, function (type) {
  return _.find(collection, function (t) {
    return t.name === type;
  });
});
```

So you have a wrapper for each item with it's own properties etc but also a children array. We could extend this to fetch children as their parent is selected from the view:

```
var Item = function (obj) {
  this.children = [];

  this.getChildren = function () {
    // Something creative here.
  };

  _.extend(this, obj);
};
```

One thing that has always confused me about composite patterns like this is, should it be done at the data level i.e. should you have Composited Data as well as Views? Or Both? Backbone Marionette's composite view relies on a collection from what I can tell:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md